# Fix try loop always going for except - else

Tags: python, pandas, csv, try-catch, read-csv

In this "try,except,else" loop, basically i didn't understand why it will *always* pick french_words.csv. IIUC, if the words_to_learn.csv exists, then it will use that csv file, and if not, then french_words.csv.

```
import pandas

french = {}
try:
    data = pandas.read_csv("data/words_to_learn.csv")
except FileNotFoundError:
    org_data = pandas.read_csv("data/french_words.csv")
    french = org_data.to_dict(orient="records")
else:
    french = data.to_dict(orient="records")

print(french)
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and trim your code according to [mre]. You should post only the relevant portion. Also please check code indentation.

Answer (score 0):

(The posted code had no indentation so I edited your question to restore it, and trimed it down to the relevant portion.)

You correctly described that this try loop means that the dictionary *french* will be preferably loaded from primary file *words_to_learn.csv*, but in absence of said file, it will resort to reading back-up file *french_words.csv* instead.

Note that if there was an error while reading *words_to_learn.csv*, that would not be covered well, as *data* would not be defined. But this is not the case, since you do not report such error.

Now why would the script always resort to loading from the back-up?
Please validate the presence of the primary file, and report it in your question, by inserting this in your code:

```py
import os.path as osp

primary_file = "data/words_to_learn.csv"

print(osp.isfile(primary_file))
```

If that returns False, you have your answer.

If True, then we keep talking.